# Database design with multiple checkbox in a form

Tags: database, database-design

What are the different ways for storing multiple choices values in table? In a form i am having around 30 to 50 sub division in which each subdivision has around 5- 10 checkboxes. how do i design the database, one way to do it, store each field in the table set it to true or false but the thing i am finding it difficult to design is that if i design it this way, i will end up have around hundred columns. any insight about optimizing. how about using xml for the values in the checkbox instead using database.

Comment: ask yourself how you intend to use this data (beyond the data entry form).  In this situation, I usually structure this type of thing for how I will query (search) it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a few ways to solve this. the most common approach would be to store the selected value in table.

```
create table division
    id (pk)
    name

create table option
    id (pk)
    name

create table divisionoption
   division id (pk)
   option id (pk)
```

with this model you can add additional options and selected options are stored in the divisionoption table.

another approach would be to assign binary values to each option and then sum the options and store the value in a single field

```
create table division
    id (pk)
    name 
    options

create table option
    id (pk) [examples: 1,2,4,8,16...]
    name
```

when it's time to save add up the values and store them in the division table.
example
option 1 - 1
option 2 - 2
option 3 - 4
option 4 - 8
user selects options 1, 2 & 3.
save the value 7 (1+2+4) to the division table.

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is to have a primary table for 'division', a lookup table for 'sub-division' types, and a pivot table for linking the two tables together. With this schema every row in the pivot table table would represent a selected checkbox for a 'division'.

Following schema is demonstrative only (as you did not indicate which RDBMS you are using), but should give you an idea.

`division`

- id int(11) unsigned not null auto_increment
- name varchar(100) not null

`division_subdivision_linking`

- id int(11) unsigned not null auto_increment
- user_id int(11) unsigned
- preference_id int(11) unsigned

`subdivision`

- id int(11) unsigned not null auto_increment
- name varchar(100) not null

You can create a form where the options to select are based on entries in the `subdivision` table, and when a user selects 'subdivision', you would insert/delete from the `division_subdivision_linking` table accordingly.